# How to Save a Query Set of Objects in a Single Transaction without using a for loop in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Just a quick question, for ex, posts variable has n objects, and i need to save the post id in a post_tag model, how can i achieve without using a for loop, and just with the a single transaction using Django ORM.

Here is a small snippet what i want to achieve:

```
posts = Post_Tag.objects.filter(tag_id = subcat).values_list('post_id', flat = True)
for post in posts:
   post_home_feed = Post_Home_Feed.objects.create(post_id = post.post_id, user_id = user_id.id)
```

Any leads much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop is not the problem, the problem is that you make *n* trips to the database for *n* objects. You can create objects in *bulk* with [**`.bulk_create(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create):

```
posts = Post_Tag.objects.filter(tag_id=subcat).values_list('post_id', flat=True)

data = [
    Post_Home_Feed(post_id=post.post_id, user_id=user_id.id)
    for post in posts
]
Post_Home_Feed.objects.bulk_create(data)
```

This will thus make `Post_Home_Feed` objects in *memory* and then create records for all these objects with a single trip to the database.

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Post_Home_Feed`</s> to `PostHomeFeed`.

Comment: @williem , Thanks mate, it worked as i expected and for the clear cut explanation about the bulk create method, really appreciate it. Yes, i'd want to change all the models to PascalCase sooner, Still our application is initial stages of development and our models keeps change based on the business requirement. That said, I hope you've a great day sir :)